# mobx@6.x class store no reactive

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

when i use mobx@6.x
with the class type store do not reactive

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-react-class-store-demo-xzcuv?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: please include more of an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your fields right away or if you want to initialize them in the constructor then you need to call `makeAutoObservable` after all initializations, otherwise it won't pick up undefined fields.

```
class TestStore {
  hello: string;
  // hello = ""; // or just initialize right here with empty string, for example

  constructor() {
    this.hello = "hello world";
    // Call it after all initializations
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  setHello(str: string) {
    console.log("testStore set hello2");
    this.hello = str;
  }
}
```

More info [in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations)

Comment: If answer was helpful you can accept it or upvote! Read more in Stack Overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers